# Include multiple directories and files to makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following folder structure

```
             test(current directory which has the makefile)
                               |
                       ----------------------
                      |                      |
            source_files                 header_files
     (has all .c files)                  (has all .h files)
```

I need to make another Makefile(call it Makefile2) in the same directory that lists all these sources. How do I tell Makefile2 to look for all .c files in the source_files folder and look for header files in the header_files folder. Also how would I be able to refer to these files in my original Makefile. (NOTE: I cannot use wildcards instead only actual filesnames). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot use wildcards? Do you mean shell wildcards, or Make wildcards, or both? Does you OS have something like the unix `find` command (and if so, can you use it)?

Comment: @Beta I cannot do a wildcard search using shell commands.I need to add the list of files to makefile2 and then use them in the original makefile.

Answer (score 1):

The Make [wildcard function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard source_files/*.c)
```

Note that this is a wildcard function, not a shell command. Put it in `makefile2`, then in `makefile` put:

```
include makefile2
```

Then you can use the variable `SOURCES`. (You can do the same with `HEADERS`.)

Comment: I did try what you suggested but that doesn't seem to work I have edited the question to include my complete code if that helps.

Comment: @user2808264: You seem to have added, then removed your code, perhaps when you noticed your typo. And you've been here long enough to know about [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); your `makefile` is far more complicated than it must be to test this solution.